What are the pros and cons of the classic portfolio by Wealthfront?
I am working on structuring my index investments exactly as provided by Wealthfront. They have the following index funds -

US stocks
Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF (VTI)
45%
Municipal bonds
Vanguard Tax-Exempt Bond Index ETF (VTEB)
16%
Foreign developed stocks
Vanguard FTSE Developed Markets ETF (VEA)
15%
Emerging market stocks
Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets ETF (VWO)
15%
Dividend growth stocks
Vanguard Dividend Appreciation ETF (VIG)
9%

I am a beginner in investments and am paranoid about buying the wrong index funds. Could someone please critically analyze these index funds for me?

Advising on particular funds is out of scope here. Folks can probably tell you whether what you have set up matches what you think you set up.

Sorry, about that. Could you please clarify what this means - "what you have set up matches what you think you set up."

Whether the kinds of funds you mention are indeed in the category you want. Selecting only tax-exempt bonds is a particular trade-off beyond a basic bond fund, and may or may not be the best choice.

That isn't a bad mix. Whether it's the best mix for you depend on your age and "time horizon", and your own risk tolerance and willingness to stay with a strategy.
I often suggest spending a bit of time and money on a fee-only financial advisor (one who just helps you make a plan rather than trying to sell you anything in particular). They can talk you through a few scenarios to understand your comfort with and trust in the market, combine that with when you will actually need the money, and suggest a more specific mixture validated a combination of market analysis and simulation. Small changes can significantly affect how volatile the overall mixture will be.

So there are a few approaches to this and you have to decide what is right for you.  You can hire a financial adviser full time, hire a fee only financial adviser as keshlam said, or use something like WealthFront.  You can also learn on your own and avoid paying fees.  In my mind it is criminal to pay the WealthFront fees for something so obvious.
Here is your first lesson:  Building wealth is about 90% behavior and 10% knowledge or math.
You are on good footing already by looking into this.
So what are your goals?  For the majority of us in the US we are looking to build a sufficient retirement nest egg.  There could be other goals as well but this is the one that is most suited to index investing over time.
While the mix you state isn't bad (its called an asset allocation model).  You probably be better off going 100% into VFIAX or VTI.  The asset allocation model is designed to protect you against short term downswings.   But if your time frame is long why do you need to be protected against such?  Also if you don't have much invested who cares if your investments drop by 20 or 30%?  You won't need the money for a long time so you have time to recover.
So my recommendation would be to invest 100% into an S&P500 fund/ETF or a Total Market fund/ETF with low fees.  Both Fidelity and Vanguard offer these and they are wonderful companies to work with.  I tend to prefer Fidelity, but Vanguard would be my second choice.
Then learn.
It takes fortitude to be a long term investor, and you know you meet a good one when the market is down sharply.  If they fret and are upset you know they have no idea what they are doing.  If instead they are "digging in the couch cushions" looking to invest more while the market is on sale then you have an investor.

"Also if you don't have much invested who cares if your investments drop by 20 or 30%? " -> Actually I am a grad student trying to maximize my Roth IRA. Therefore, I will be putting a big chunk of my savings (except my emergency fund) into this. Therefore, I am quite worried.

@desert_ranger why?  That money is, at the soonest, meant for the time you are in your 50s.  It will recover.  Timing the market is impossible.

Got it. Thank you.

If it is money you are going to need in the short term, it doesn't belong in the market; look at certificates of deposit, high interest savings accounts, and possibly money market accounts if you want to push the boundaries. If it is money for the long-term, you are at an ideal point in your investing career to (with appropriate caution) take greater risks in the hope of greater returns. As you approach retirement, you will gradually shift that trade - off to put more emphasis on retaining wealth rather than gaining wealth.

Even though it's well known, it's worth mentioning that one of main things you want to consider when looking at funds is the 'load' meaning how much the fund charges you to manage it. The good news here is that, since this is Vanguard, you can pretty much assume you are getting some of the lowest (if not lowest) load funds available.
Also, mutual funds are great for tax sheltered accounts like 401Ks or IRAs but if you are outside of that, ETFs have tax advantages over funds. The same logic applies when it comes to fees and I believe Vanguard offers equivalent ETFs for their popular mutual funds (even though Bogle hated ETFs.)
